# iOS 8 MKMapView User Location Request Failure

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, ios8, cllocationmanager

I have been trying to move my iOS7 app with MKMapview to support iOS8. However I couldn't get the new request for users to share their locations to work properly. I create my MKMapView on a storyboard and the delegate is set and works perfectly on iOS7. Here is what I've added to support iOS8 Location sharing:

**myMapView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface myMapView : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
```

**myMapView.m**

```
//Code omitted
#define IS_OS_8_OR_LATER ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
//Code omitted
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;

    if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
        //[self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
        [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
    [self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
    [self.mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow animated:YES];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    MKCoordinateRegion region = { { 0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } };
    region.center.latitude = self.locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude;
    region.center.longitude = self.locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude;
    region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.0187f;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.0137f;
    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
    
    _initialPosition = NO;
}
```

Also I have set `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` key and its value in my InfoPlist, which shows the correct message when prompting the user to share their location.

Unfortunately the delegate function `-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations` never gets called. Although each time the viewController gets loaded the `[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation]` is called, but the delegate does not seem to respond to it. Is there a problem of how I set the delegate or is there something else I am missing here?

**UPDATE:** It seems also that my gpx file is not being called on launch. I have cleared and reloaded my location file, even changed to a default location, but no location is found: `Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0`

**UPDATE 2:** Here is a SS from the settings that I have actually succeeded with the user request, but fail to get/update location no matter how much I refresh.
[image: App privacy level: Location sharing always]
<sub>(source: [barisaltop.com](http://barisaltop.com/location.png))</sub>

Thanks!

Comment: Same problem for me also. Did you find any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem a few days ago. The solution was adding the `string` keys `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` (for `[CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization]`) or `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` (for `[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization]`)  to your **Supporting Files/Info.plist**

You can also edit the source code of the `Info.Plist` with **Right click > open as > Source code** and add these lines:

```
<!-- for requestAlwaysAuthorization -->
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Explain for what are you using the user location</string>
<!-- for requestWhenInUseAuthorization -->
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Explain for what are you using the user location</string>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately I have already done this and mentioned it in my original question.
After further review I am suspicious that this a scheme or gpx file error. I will test it on a iOS8 machine and update my problem.

Comment: Ups, I missed that part. Sorry! :)

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have succeeded to run my gpx file on the simulator. It seems that after installing Xcode 6 the first time, there might be a bug causing for gpx files to simulate. Here is how I overcame the problem:

1. I have deleted my app from the simulator
2. Under App->Capabilities enabled Background Modes->Location updates
3. Run the app and let it install on simulator
4. **Allow access, and I was able to locate the user with GPX**
5. Afterwards I disabled Location Updates.

I don't know why, but this did the trick for me.

Comment: I have the same problem. Can't get it to work in my iPod touch. What might be the reason?