# MKMapView tiles not loaded with zoom

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mkmapview, mapkit

I've got an issue. I'm using a `MKMapView` for displaying some annotations. I initialize a map view with default zoom. And it displays some map.

[image]

but when i try zooming, tiles not loaded, and map becomes empty. Like this.

[image]

I create my Map View via interface builder.

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet MKMapView* mapView;
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there any mandatory methods for implementation, that affect on this functional? And yes, there is an internet connection on my device.

Comment: Have you found the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Generally this can happens due to internet connection. If you have slow internet connection than it takes time to load map tiles.

About methods i recommended to override below method.

Override `MKMapView` delegate method -

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

Will call every time you zoom in/out and load map tiles.

PS - provide `MKMapViewDelegate` to your view controller.

Comment: But an internet connection is available, and tiles never loaded after zoom. I don't understand why.

Comment: Post your code that How you create `MKMapView, Which delegates you are using.

Comment: I don't know why, but it works on other devices. With same iOS 7. I create it with interface builder and set delegate in IB.

Answer (score -3):

I had the same loading problem till I got the problem working by googling!

**Note**: Effective ios 8 & later, we need to add a value `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` in **Info.plist** file with our own value as description. This is because `showsUserLocation` property of `**MKMapView**` doesn't work straight away. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25848125/ios-8-mkmapview-user-location-request-failure) !!!!

```
//This should be declared in .h file
@property(nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    self.mapView.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
    if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
#endif
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {
    if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways || status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse) {
        self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    }
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center = self.locationView.userLocation.coordinate;

    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta  = 0.015; ->Adjust this value to zoom as per your requirement
    span.longitudeDelta = 0.015;
    region.span = span;

    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

I firmly believe this will yield the expected result without fail, i.e. MKMapView zoom to the current user location.

Comment: Use location permission is only necessary if you want to show the user's location.  You don't need user location permission to show maps.