# CLLocationManager location updating over wifi?

Tags: ios, cllocation

I have a new problem with location updating in iOS8.

in `viewDidAppear` I call my location manager:

```
//start location updating
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

however this void

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{
    currentLocation = newLocation;
}
```

never gets called.
It's weird, I'm quite sure it worked when I was in Finland still (using my cellular data). Now I'm travelling in Brasil (only using wifi) and I cannot get it to work here, which is totally weird. my wifi access point seems to be known so I'm confused.
any ideas?

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12602463/didupdatelocations-instead-of-didupdatetolocation. Anyway, GPS shouldn't need WIFI to get locations, but it does need open space to be seen by the satellites.

Comment: this post relates to iOS6. I've never supported iOS 6 and it's always worked before

Comment: It was supposed to be deprecated since iOS 6! `didUpdateLocations` is more reliable.

Comment: changed it but that one also doesn't get called

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25848125/ios-8-mkmapview-user-location-request-failure

Comment: I have also the same problem can anybody have some string solution . I am following all new iOS 8 changes still my CLLocationManager is not working over wifi.

Answer (score 0):

the answer to the problem is some news in how iOS8 handles location updating. There is an awesome post about it here:
http://nevan.net/2014/09/core-location-manager-changes-in-ios-8/